# scheme pattern checking if it is a number

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, pattern-matching, racket

I am a scheme beginner and

I am wondering how to explain this piece of scheme code? Looks so preculiar!

```
(define (calc2 exp)
   (match exp                                
     [(? number? x)  x]))
```

I know match gives a pattern, but how to explain this weird pattern?

```
 (? number? x)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(? expr pat ...)` is part of the syntax of the `match` macro. It applies `expr` to the patterns and checks whether the result is a true value. In this case, that means it will check if `(number? x)` returns true, where `x` is `exp`. If it does, the function will return whatever you passed to it as `exp`. If not, it will raise a match exception.

In other words, calc2 simply raises an exception for any value passed to it that is not a number, and returns it's argument otherwise. For more information on how pattern matching works in Racket, check out http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html

Comment: Thanks, Maxwell! I am just wondering why it is not (match exp [(number? exp) exp]), how does x got assigned exp's value? By the way, it is really hard to google this sort of question

Comment: `In this case, that means it will check if (number? x) returns true`. This is incorrect, x cannot be checked if it number or not as there is x variable bound to any value

Answer (score 1):

`(? number? x)` in this when the pattern matching detects a `?` as first item in the pattern then it and's all the predicates after the `?`. So in this case it means that your `exp` should be a number and then as x is not a predicate it just mean set x same as `exp`.

From the documentation:

> (? expr pat ...) — applies expr to the value to be matched, and checks
>   whether the result is a true value; the additional pats must also
>   match; i.e., ? combines a predicate application and an and pattern.
>   However, ?, unlike and, guarantees that expr is matched before any of
>   the pats.

Example:

```
> (match '(1 3 5)
   [(list (? odd?) ...) 'yes])
'yes
```

Comment: Thanks, would you give an example about (? expr pat) but expr is not a predicate like number?

Comment: Added an example, exp has to be a function that when applied to value should return true or false